# Waking up a sleeping locked android not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-permissions

I use the `ALARM_SERVICE` with the following `BroadcastReceiver`, in oreder to start my `OnReceiveActivity`:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try {

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.test", "co.test.OnReceiveActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

            i.addFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED +
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON +
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                     );

            context.startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try it without any of the specified `WindowManager.LayoutParams` flags (while the device is awake and unlocked) - everything works as expected, meaning `onReceive()` is called, and starts `OnReceiveActivity` successfully. however, when the flags are present, it doesn't work, neither when the device is asleep and looked, nor when its awake and unlocked.

The following permission were specified at the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare commented, `WindowManager.LayoutParams` flags are not Intent flags.

The right way to it is within the `onCreate()` of `OnReceiveActivity`, using `getWindow()` function as follow:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED +
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD +
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON +
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
    );
```

The way I did it before was used in many examples that I've seen, which makes it quite odd.

Comment: @notbatlinux  Instead of writing new answer you should try to edit the answer from which you got hint of the solution and accept that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Those are not `Intent` flags and cannot be used with `addFlags()` on `Intent`.

Comment: It seemed to work for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113161/start-activity-screen-even-if-screen-is-locked-in-android) guy.. In any case, how could I add them? @commonsware

Comment: @nobatlinux: In the activity being started, pass those flags to `getWindow().addFlags()`.

Comment: yep just got it :) added an answer for future seekers.