# Launch a single activity as lock screen when the screen on or off

Tags: android

how to call a single activity(screen lock) of my lock screen app when my phone screen on and off,
I am trying but not achive my target. please help me I am tired. I call activity from the Broadcast Receiver but this launches activity only my app is running when the app close the activity not launches.
REciver is `

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { Toast.makeText(context, "BroadcastReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Intent lockIntent = new Intent(context, Lockview.class);
        lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(lockIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Screen is lock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Screen is unlocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent lockIntent = new Intent(context, Lockview.class);
        lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(lockIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Screen is book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }`
```

and the MAnifest is `

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AEScreenOnOffReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`    and the activity where I trigger the Reciver is   ` BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast=new AEScreenOnOffReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));

    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED));` in the oncreate
```

Comment: I have edited my post please help

Comment: Have you added these in your mainfest ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` and 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />`

Comment: yesI have   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113161/start-activity-screen-even-if-screen-is-locked-in-android

Comment: sir I have see this, my problem is this that I cannot launch my activity when the app is not running. when the app running My broadcastreceiver work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my Problem of launching the activity as a Screen lock direct from the Broadcast Receiver when the screen on. only by changing my Manifest receiver declaration as bellow   `<receiver
            android:name=".AEScreenOnOffReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`