# How to start an Android App From Lockscreen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

Is it possible to start an app from the lockscreen *without* unlocking the phone?

Every time I lock my phone and want to use it again, I must enter a password or the correct sequence of pattern to be able to use my phone.
But I want to add an specific app on the lockscreen as a shortcut, so that I don't need to enter a pass or a sequence of pattern to be able to open the app.

Is this possible?

I want to open an app added on the lockscreen without unlocking the screen.

I have tried looking for solutions but cant seem to find any.

Comment: You can't do bypass the lockscreen to launch the entire application. You can however create a lockscreen widget to control the application from the lockscreen

Comment: is there absolutely noway to bybass the lockscreen to launch the app?

Comment: because the camera app is able to launch from lockscreen if im correct

Comment: Yes the camera is able to but no other application is able to launch before the lockscreen has been cleared. The camera is able to be abled to be used because it uses:
MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE

There is no similar thing for anything else except a camera.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE

Comment: so what other options do i have? is there anything that one can do without clearing lockscreen?

Comment: You don't have any other way around clearing the lockscreen before using the application. Android is designed this way to prevent unauthorized users from accessing any applications on your device without clearing the lockscreen. Without it there wouldn't even be a point of having a lockscreen

Comment: app like wechat is able to receive call, and start itself even if the phone is screen off and locked

Comment: Ok I found the solution, you can't bypass the phone lock programmatically, but it is possible to display the activity before phone is unlock, stackoverflow.com/a/55998126/5777189

Answer (score 1):

you need this permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

[original post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20113435/7047252)